# DETERMINISTIC and NON-DETERMINISTIC function in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

my understaning for Deterministic function is that :

> always produces the same result for the same input parameters

as per my understanding below function is Nonderministic function

```
CREATE FUNCTION foo (val INT) READS SQL DATA
BEGIN
   DECLARE retval INT;
   SET retval = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table_1 WHERE field_1 = val);
   RETURN retval;
END;
```

If i dont use Deterministic or Nondeterministic keyword in function will it degreade performance or is it necessary for execution plan.

Comment: `If neither DETERMINISTIC nor NOT DETERMINISTIC is given in the routine definition, the default is NOT DETERMINISTIC.`. And `Declaring a nondeterministic routine as DETERMINISTIC might lead to unexpected results by causing the optimizer to make incorrect execution plan choices. Declaring a deterministic routine as NONDETERMINISTIC might diminish performance by causing available optimizations not to be used.`. See [13.1.16 CREATE PROCEDURE and CREATE FUNCTION Syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-procedure.html).

Answer (score 3):

When you declare a function to be deterministic, the query planner knows it can take advantage of cached results for that function. It may speed things up. Pretty much no function that looks in tables can be deterministic.

If you're not sure whether your function is deterministic, it probably isn't.